# PL/SQL Developer - last character is missing in the results grid

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper, string-length

We have a table with a column name `A` with type `nvarchar(23)`.

following query will always return `23` which means that the actual length of all records are `23`.

```
select length(trim(req.A)), count(*)
  from tableName req
group by length(trim(req.A));
```

```
|length(trim(req.A))|count(*)| 
------------------------------
|23                 |1006    |
```

But when we select from this table with following query it behaves different and it seems that the last character is always removed in result Gridview in PL/SQL Developer.

```
select LENGTHB(req.A) lenb, length(req.A) len, req.* from tableName req
where req.A = 'NHBBBBB1398052635902235'; -- Note to the equal sign and the last charactar (5) of the where clause
```

the result is:

```
|lenb|len|          A           |
---------------------------------
|46  |23 |NHBBBBB139805263590223|
```

As you can see the last character (**`5`**) is removed in the select result.

Also when we rewrite previous query with `to_char()` it works fine & return correct result with the length of **`23`** and (**`5`**) as the last character.

```
select LENGTHB(req.A) lenb, length(req.A) len, to_char(req.A) from tableName req
where req.A = 'NHBBBBB1398052635902235';
```

the result is:

```
|lenb|len|    to_char(req.A)     |
----------------------------------
|46  |23 |NHBBBBB1398052635902235|
```

Can you please explain whats happen!? Is this related to PL/SQL Developer configs? How to solve this?

Comment: PL/SQL and PL/SQL Developer are two completely different things. I think you mean the second one.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yes, You're right. Tanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is a bug caused by the different character sets of oracle db you'r connected on and the client you executed that query on.
Some character sets is a mutibyte like 'AL32UTF8' character set which can use multiple bytes to store one character.

so you could check the character set of your db using:

```
select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter like '%SET%';
```

and try setting `NLS_LANG` character set to the character set used by your client application and try again.

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. 
Our production environment are completely isolated and requesting these kind of actions needs passing a bunch of annoying "bureaucracy layer"! Unfortunately we couldn't reproduce this behavior in our dev/test environments. Anyway, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was an **old version of PL/SQL Developer** which our customers used. When they updated to the newer version, the problem has been solved.